# No FIQ.h on Raspberry PI3B+

Tags: pi-3b+, linux, kernel, software-development, interrupts

I was exploring the FQI routine for ARM processors. I noticed that most Linux kernels provide a `fiq.h` header file yet my RPi does not seem to have it. Using `find` does not return anything. My Linux kernel version is `5.15.61-v8+`. How would one use FIQ without the header file on RPI? Thanks.

```
robin@raspberrypi:/ $ locate interrupt.h
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_interrupt.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.61-v8+/include/linux/interrupt.h

robin@raspberrypi:/ $ locate fiq.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.61-v8+/include/linux/platform_data/ams-delta-fiq.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.61-v8+/include/linux/spi/s3c24xx-fiq.h
```

Comment: Not everything from the kernel source is in the headers package:  https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/rpi-5.15.y/arch/arm/include/asm/fiq.h (may or may not be what you are looking for)